# Hide item when is reaching the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, show-hide

In the `body` of the page I have a div with `max-height` and `overflow-scroll`. It contains a list of words. And it also contains a title with `position fixed`. I want that when this title reach the end of the box, hide. How can I do? My code doesn't work.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/bsafpmyp/

Jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
  var fadeFlag = false;

  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
 if ($("#box1").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
    $('#target').fadeOut();
    fadeFlag = true;

} else {
    if(fadeFlag) $('#target').fadeIn();
    fadeFlag = false;
}
});
```

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question exactly what you want to happen. If the title is in a fixed position, then it's not going to move (as you can see in your JSFiddle) - so how will it reach the end of the box?

Comment: See the answer of Siderite, that is correct. Then maybe you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bsafpmyp/3/
The point is to use the properties of box1, not window, and to use the scrollHeight, which doesn't exist in jQuery as a function and instead you use `$('#box1')[0].scrollHeight`